# Group by result of count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First, this is with Microsoft SQL Server 2014

I've got two tables in a database, Shipment and Package. Each shipment has a Shipment_ID, and each package has both a Shipment_ID and a Package_ID. A shipment can be made up of more than one package, i.e. multiple packages can have the same Shipment_ID.

I'm trying to figure out the number of shipments I have with per amount of packages.

So, something like this:

| Count Packages | Number of Shipments |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,000,000 |
| 2 | 250,000 |
| 3 | 100,000 |
| 4 | 5,000 |
| 5 | 1,000 |

I've figured out how to get the number of packages for each Shipment_ID, which I've done like this:

```
SELECT s.Shipment_ID, COUNT(p.Package_ID)
FROM Shipment s
LEFT JOIN Package p ON s.Shipment_ID = p.Shipment_ID
GROUP BY s.Shipment_ID
```

This is where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to consolidate this down to the number of shipments for each package count.

My first thought was to somehow group by `COUNT(p.Package_ID)`, but aggregate functions can't be used in group by.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I don;t follow what you're after here. Sample data to compliment your expected results will help us help you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your query as a sub-query and slap another query over the top.

```
SELECT ShipmentCount, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT s.Shipment_ID, COUNT(p.Package_ID) ShipmentCount
    FROM Shipment s
    LEFT JOIN Package p on s.Shipment_ID = p.Shipment_ID
    GROUP BY s.Shipment_ID
) X
GROUP BY ShipmentCount;
```